# Git: Deploy only a directory from post-receive hook

Tags: git, deployment

Having followed the instructions from [this article](http://blog.brandonevans.ca/post/19685508893/deploying-websites-with-git-on-dreamhost) I have a post-receive hook which currently reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/user/example.com --git-dir=/home/user/example.com.git checkout -f
```

This is working well - all the files and directories are getting deployed. However I'd like to only deploy the files from the Build folder within example.com.git (I'm using [Hammer](http://hammerformac.com/) by the way.) so not all the development files are available and viewable on the live server.

**Question:** What do I alter/add to the above Git command in order to only checkout/deploy what's within the Build directory?

**Update:**
After the discussion in the comments I came to the following, which works in my case.

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/user/example.com --git-dir=/home/user/example.com.git checkout -f master -- Build/
cd /home/user/example.com
cp -rRp Build/. .
rm -rf Build
```

Comment: Don't you end up with unwanted files in . with your self provided answer? Everything other than Build/ would still be there, no? I think @yanhan's answer (to use the <paths> arg of git checkout) is better.

Comment: I tried @yanhan's answer and it gave few git errors while this ^ answer didn't give any errors, however didn't do a job either. Git push completes successfully but the remote repo remains empty (unchanged). 
:/

Answer (score 8):

I'll abbreviate the values supplied to `--work-tree` and `--git-dir` as `WT` and `REPO` respectively so that everything can fit without a horizontal scrollbar.

The general form should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=WT --git-dir=REPO checkout -f -- paths
```

Suppose at the `WT` directory that's being deployed on the live server, you only want to checkout the `Build` folder in the repository. This becomes

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=WT --git-dir=REPO checkout -f -- Build
```

In general, you can replace the `paths` portion with one or more files in the git repository. These are specified as relative paths according to how they are placed in the repo. So if your git repo looks like this:

```
FolderOne
|- FolderTwo
|  |- FileOne
|- FolderThree

FolderFour
|- FileFive
```

And you want to checkout `FileOne` and everything `FolderFour`, you should do:

```
git --work-tree=WT --git-dir=REPO checkout -f -- FolderOne/FolderTwo/FileOne FolderFour
```

**UPDATE:**

It's been some time since I've dealt with Git hooks, but I think other than some details like their stdin and argv, you can put anything inside.

So for checking out everything in the `Build` folder but not the `Build` folder itself, you could do something like this in the post-receive hook:

```
git --work-tree=WT --git-dir=REPO checkout -f -- Build/
cd WT
cp -r Build/* .
rmdir Build
```

So we first checkout the `Build` directory into the `WT` directory. Then we `cd` into the `WT` directory, copy everything out from the `Build` directory using `cp -r Build/* .` . The `.` stands for the current directory, which is the `WT` directory we just `cd` into. Once that's done, we remove the now empty `Build` directory.

Hence, everything from the `Build` directory is now checked out into the `WT` directory, without the `Build` directory itself. Of course, you've got to replace `WT` and `REPO` by the actual paths to the work tree and git repository respectively.

Hope that helps

Comment: This works. Though I'd like to include everything inside the Build folder, yet not the folder itself. I tried using Build/*, but didn't have any luck with that.

Comment: In that case, I believe that you could just do something along the lines of `cp -r REPO/Build/* WorkTree` in the hook

Comment: Could you spell it out for me? I'm not very used to Git. I tried some variations of this with my own filepaths, but with no results.

Comment: Hi Eystein, I've updated the answer. Do note that I've not tried out the code above, so you might want to try it somewhere other than the actual deployment folder itself.

Comment: Thanks @yanhan, the update got me on the right track. I used `cp -rRp Build/. .` to include the `htaccess` file since `*` ignored invisible files,  and `rm -rf Build` to force erase the directory even though it's not empty. It works as I want it to, but I'm not 100% sure how `-rRp` differs from just `-r`.

Comment: Yea I didn't realize that `*` does not copy over the files beginning with a `.`. As for `cp`, a lookup on the `cp` manpage tells me that the `-r` and `-R` flags are the same, so using any one of them will do instead of both of them together. The `-p` flag is the same as `--preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps`.

Comment: I see this has already been discussed before but another option, perhaps more straightforward, is that you change the whole structure of your git setup so that Build/ is actually the repo you checkout in the deploy folder.

Answer (score 1):

yanhan's solution did not work for me.. here is my approach...

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="/htdocs/my-project/public"
TEMP="/htdocs/my-project/tmp"
PUBLIC="/htdocs/my-project/tmp/public"
GIT_DIR="/htdocs/my-project/test.git"
BRANCH="master"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref = refs/heads/$BRANCH ]];
    then
        # create temp directory
        mkdir $TEMP
        # check out the master branch
        git --work-tree=$TEMP --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f 
        # remove current target files and directory
        rm -rf $TARGET
        # move contents of the chosen folder to the target 
        mv $PUBLIC $TARGET
        # delete the tmp directory since not needed anymore..
        rm -rf $TEMP
    fi
done
```