# How can I deploy only one folder using git hooks?

Tags: git, hook, git-post-receive

Set up git hooks on my godaddy linux cPanel the other day 
Got it working and all. 
However, The way I have set up couple of projects is that I have a **/src** folder and a **/public** folder which obviously contains the assets I want to serve on a server.

I do have a .gitignore file but I still like to push development code to my github. 
So, the question - is it possible to ignore those development files and folders in the post-receive git hook ?

I've followed examples provided in this old QA - [Git: Deploy only a directory from post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033437/git-deploy-only-a-directory-from-post-receive-hook), but unsuccessfully.

I've tried multiple variations of the following code

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/user/public_html/hm --git-dir=/home/user/repo/hm.git checkout -f -- public/
cd home/user/public_html/hm
cp -r public/. .
rm -rf  public
```

And that's the error that I get

```
zeMachine:hm username$ git push live
Counting objects: 519, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (502/502), done.
Writing objects: 100% (519/519), 10.08 MiB | 155.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 519 (delta 255), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: pathspec 'public/' did not match any file(s) known to git.
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 3: cd: home/user/public_html/hm: No such file or directory
remote: cp: cannot stat `public/.': No such file or directory
To ssh://example.com/home/user/repo/hm.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

public folder does exist but as you see you start questioning after some time :D 
Also, if I delete everything that comes after -f 
the code works but again, then I have all the development files and folders that I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
try inserting this into post-receive

```
# The production directory
TARGET="/srv/www/<your-app>"
# A temporary directory for deployment
TEMP="/srv/tmp/<your-app>"
# The Git repo
REPO="/srv/git/<your-app>.git"
# Deploy the content to the temporary directory
mkdir -p $TEMP
git --work-tree=$TEMP --git-dir=$REPO checkout -f
cd $TEMP
# Do stuffs, like npm install…
# Replace the production directory
# with the temporary directory
cd /
rm -rf $TARGET
mv $TEMP $TARGET
```

source: https://medium.com/@francoisromain/vps-deploy-with-git-fea605f1303b